# How to execute a list of checks with Gnu Make?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a `Makefile` that should execute some simple commands on a set of imput files. Each does not have an output, just the success of the command should be checked:

```
# Makefile
check: test1 test2 test3

test1: one.xml
    xmllint --schema my.xsd $@
test2: two.xml
    xmllint --schema my.xsd $@
test3: three.xml
    xmllint --schema my.xsd $@
```

I would like to have this more generic, that I don't have to list identical rules for each file. Which is especially inconvenient when I for example use `$(wildcard ...)`:

```
# Makefile (sketch only)
XMLS:=$(wildcard *.xml)

check: xmllint

xmllint: %.xml   # this will not work will it?  
    xmllint --schema my.xsd $@
```

The last rule isnor correct, of course, since the `%` is on the right side:

> $ make check
>
> *** No rule to make target '%.xml', needed by 'xmllint'.  Stop.

How do I connect the `$(XMLS)` input files with the `xmllint: ...` rule, so that on `make check` the program `xmllint` is executed on all xml input files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.PHONY: all check

# The files to be tested
XMLS:=$(wildcard *.xml)

# Turning the filenames into *test* names
XMLTESTS:=$(patsubst %.xml,%.test,$(XMLS))

# "make check" should run all tests
check: $(XMLTESTS)

# Each test depends on the XML file
# Now we have a pattern on both sides of the generic rule
%.test: %.xml
    xmllint --schema my.xsd $<
```

Note that, for some (to me) unknown reason, putting `.PHONY` after the declarations and adding `$(XMLTESTS)` to it results in "nothing to be done for target 'all'". I have no idea why.

**EDIT:** `.PHONY:` does not work for implicit rules and pattern rules.